# Referencing .NET 4.6.2 class library from .NET Core app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, project.json

I'm using VS Update 3 (14.0.25425.01). Here's what I've done:

1. Create ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core)
2. Create Class Library .Net 4.6.2
3. Add `net462` to frameworks, `netcoreapp1.0`, imports in project.json
4. Right click on ASP.Net Core app, click Add Reference, select Projects, select Class Library you created in step 2.

I get no errors on restoring and the reference is added to the ASP.Net Core app.  However, I cannot access it.  I cannot add a using import declaration or access the objects.  I've ran through many things but nothing seems to work and the posts are very versioned fragmented.

[image]

Here is the Program.cs in the ASP.Net Core App.
[image]

[image]

**Update**
I did what Nate suggested.  I thought I tried this already..but sure enough I can now access my 4.6.2 libraries.  However, I'm now getting compile errors.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does work in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, but your `project.json` isn't quite right.

Instead of adding `net462` to the `imports` section, it should be in the `frameworks` section:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": { },
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency also needs to be moved into the `netcoreapp1.0` section. That's because this dependency is only required when compiling as a .NET Core application.

The reference to your .NET 4.6.2 library is then simply part of your `dependencies` section:

```
"dependencies": {
  (...)
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
  "MyLibrary": {
    "target": "project"
  }
}
```

By structuring it this way, I was able to reference and use classes in my .NET 4.6.2 library without any problems.

---

For reference, here's the entire working `project.json` I used:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "MyLibrary": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Comment: Does that actually compile for `netcoreapp1.0` or only for `net461`?

Comment: @svick With both Visual Studio and `dotnet build`, binaries are produced for both `net461` and `netcoreapp1.0`.

Comment: How? A `netcoreapp1.0` app shouldn't be able to depend on a `net461` library, that's just not compatible.

Comment: @svick...am I doing something wrong here?  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @NateBarbettini See my Updated question. I know this looks obvious but what impact does this have? The project builds successfully and runs

Answer (score 1):

@NateBarbettini answer accomplished my original question.  But I could not run ASP.Net Core Web Application version 1 with my .Net 4.6.1 project as it was because it could not find a .NetCore.App v1 assembly for my .Net 4.6.1 project.  So I added a project.json to my .Net 4.6.1 project with the following project.json.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.6": {
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
   },
  "net461": {}
 }
}
```

Next, in the ASP.Net Core Web Application modify the project.json by adding a dependency under the .NetCore.App.  This way it will pick up both versions, 4.6.1 and .NetCore v1.

```
...
"frameworks": {
"net461": {
  "dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrary1": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  }
},
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8",
    "net461"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "ClassLibrary1": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  }
}
}
```

So far so good, I can develop in .Net 4.6.1 and it will work running under .NetCore.App v1.  However, I think there will be issues when I have other dependencies in my .Net 4.6.1 projects.

Comment: What other dependencies will cause issues in your .NET 4.6.1 project?